# Minimizing the loss function seems counterintuitive

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent

Loss functions I've known of always returns a positive value so that gradient descent can minimize them. Let's take a regression problem. Suppose my NN underestimate the result by x, then the loss would be the same as if it overestimate the result by x. Intuitively, should the optimizing algorithm do the opposite thing?

Are (1) make the math and implementation simpler, and (2) so far it had been working the reason we keep doing this?

Was asked in StackOverflow but here seems to be a more suitable community.

Comment: "Suppose my NN underestimate the result by x, then the loss would be the same as if it overestimate the result by x." Note that most algorithms work most directly with *gradients* rather than loss function values. Try computing the gradient of the loss at an overestimate and at an equal underestimate for MSE. You'll find that the intuition from "Intuitively, should the optimizing algorithm do the opposite thing?" is mathematically validated.